# What is the integral of $ \int e^x \sin^{-1}xdx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How does one integrate: $$ I= \int e^x sin^{-1}xdx $$
I've tried doing this by parts but in the end, I just get I=I. Does this mean the function is "unintegratable"(if something as such exists)?

PS: I'm very new to calculus so this question might just be stupid.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you get after integrating by parts?

Comment: You have to be careful with integration by parts. You can easily undo what you did if you don't pick your variables right.

Comment: "Unintegrable" functions definitely exist. The standard example of an unsolvable integral is $\int e^{-x^2}dx$.

Comment: How is $\int e^{-x^2} \, dx$ unintegrable. Do you mean not obtainable in closed form?

Comment: Wolframalpha says no closed form integral, maybe it is wrong or perhaps you need a definite integral?

Comment: This integral does not appear to have a closed form, are you sure it's not $\int e^x\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: This question was given to me by a friend of mine. I'm not sure what the original question was, but it might actually have been $ \int e^x sinxdx $ , which seems quite solvable. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Integration does produce new kinds of functions. For example $\log x =\int \frac {1}{x}dx$ cannot be expressed in rational functions and inverses of rational functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $z\in(-1,1)$ we have

$$ \int_{0}^{z}e^{-x}\arcsin(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{z}e^{-x}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{(2n+1)4^n}x^{2n+1}\,dx $$
hence the LHS can be represented as a series involving the incomplete $\Gamma$ function.
As an alternative one may exploit the Jacobi-Anger expansion
$$ e^{-z\sin\theta}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}J_n(iz)\,e^{in\theta}=I_0(z)+2\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n\left[I_{2n-1}(z)\sin((2n-1)\theta)+I_{2n}(z)\cos(2n\theta)\right] $$
to state
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{z}e^{-x}\arcsin(x)\,dx &=& \int_{0}^{\arcsin z}e^{-\sin\theta}\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta\\
&=&I_0(1)\left(-1+\sqrt{1-z^2}+z\arcsin z\right)\\&+&\scriptstyle 2\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n\left[I_{2n-1}(1)\int_{0}^{\arcsin z}\theta\cos\theta\sin((2n-1)\theta)\,d\theta+I_{2n}(1)\int_{0}^{\arcsin z}\theta\cos\theta\cos(2n\theta)\,d\theta\right]\end{eqnarray*}$$
which is a typesetting nightmare with better convergence properties, since $0\leq I_n(1)\leq \frac{I_0(1)}{2^n n!}$.
Here $I_n$ is a [modified Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

Comment: I think your answer is more useful than mine, and certainly more comprehensive. Looking up the approximations for arcsin in Hastings, they involve a polynomial times $\sqrt{1-x}$ and these, according to Wolfy, are a pain, involving erfi and other messy functions. If I had to do this, I would just use numerical integration (Romberg or adaptive Simpson), separating the larger z values where $e^{-z}$ is small.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int e^x\arcsin{x}dx=e^x\arcsin{x}-\int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$ and bye...

Answer (score 0):

$\int e^xf(x)dx
=e^xf(x)-\int e^xf'(x)dx
=e^xf(x)-e^xf'(x)+\int e^xf''(x)dx
=...$

Continue until tired.

Comment: Somebody didn't like this (and I don't blame them, much). It's a generalization of Michael Rozenberg's answer, so I will go upvote that.